# How to drag and drop controls on dynamically created tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, tablelayoutpanel

How to use drag and drop controls (created dynamically) on tablelayoutpanel ( created dynamically too).. 
I added

```
tablelayoutpanel.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(controlTable_DragDrop);
```

But doesn't enter this function.

Answer (score 0):

DragDrop function is called when you released the dropped object.

First, you have to allow objects dropping on the TableLayoutPanel:

```
tablelayoutpanel.AllowDrop = true;
```

Then, the TableLayoutPanel must accept the dropping (you can add conditions on data format and value):

```
tablelayoutpanel.DragEnter += (o, args) => args.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
```